# How to check on join table for rows in a time range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I need to search for Subscriptions, and then check each Subscription if there's any Notification related to this Subscription in the last n hours and if not, take this Subscription

I've come up with two solutions, but I'm not quite satisfied with them both. Can someone help to perform this most effectively?

Solution 1:

```
SELECT
    "Subscription"."id",
FROM
    "Subscriptions" AS "Subscription"   
WHERE
    "Subscription"."UserId" = 2
    AND "Subscription"."isActive" = TRUE
    AND "Subscription"."FeedId" = 35
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT* FROM "Notifications" AS "Notification"
        WHERE  
           "Notification"."SubscriptionId" = "Subscription"."id"
           AND (("Notification"."createdAt" > now() - interval '1 hours' AND "Notification"."CreativeId" = 70)
           OR ("Notification"."createdAt" > now() - interval '6 hours' AND "Notification"."FeedId" = 35))
    )
GROUP BY
    "Subscription"."id"

LIMIT 15000 OFFSET 0;
```

Solution  2:

```
SELECT
          "Subscription"."id",
        FROM
          "Subscriptions" AS "Subscription"
          LEFT OUTER JOIN "Notifications" AS "Notification" ON "Subscription"."id" = "Notification"."SubscriptionId" AND "Notification"."createdAt" > now()::date - interval '6 hours'
              AND ("Notification"."FeedId" = 35 OR "Notification"."CreativeId" = 70)

        WHERE
          "Subscription"."UserId" = 2
          AND "Subscription"."isActive" = TRUE
          AND "Subscription"."FeedId" =35

        GROUP BY
          "Subscription"."id"
        HAVING
          COUNT("Notification"."SubscriptionId") FILTER (WHERE "Notification"."FeedId" = 35
            AND "Notification"."createdAt" > now() - interval '6 hours') < 1
          AND
          COUNT("Notification"."SubscriptionId") FILTER (WHERE "Notification"."CreativeId" = 70
            AND "Notification"."createdAt" > now() - interval '1 hours') < 1

 LIMIT 15000 OFFSET 0;
```

When I do both in TablePlus, the first one seems to do a little better, but when I test them in my backend, the second one wins dramatically. I am trying to understand why, but since I started working with pure SQL a couple of days ago, I decided to ask here

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: The first query looks OK to me. Do you actually have a performance problem?

Comment: Interesting, didn't know this. I use Node and Sequelize on backend and therefore rarely get along in pure SQL and didn't know that it's such sensitive.

Comment: When I do both in TablePlus, the first one seems to do a little better, but when I test them in my backend, the second one wins dramatically. I am trying to understand why, but since I started working with pure SQL a couple of days ago, I decided to ask here.

Comment: Check the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `group by`.  The first solution would seem to be the way to go, but I would write it as:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM Subscriptions s  
WHERE s.user_id = 2 AND
      s.isActive AND
      s.FeedId = 35 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Notification n
                  WHERE n.SubscriptionId = s.id AND
                        n.createdAt > now() - interval '6 hours' AND
------------------------^ I added this redundant condition to help the optimizer
                        ( (n.createdAt > now() - interval '1 hours' AND n.CreativeId = 70) or
                          (n.createdAt > now() - interval '6 hours' AND n.FeedId = 35)   
                        )
                 )
LIMIT 15000 OFFSET 0;
```

For performance, you want indexes on `subscriptions(user_id, is_active, feed_id)` and `notifications(subscription_id, created_at, creative_id, feed_id)`.

Notes:

- I removed all the double quotes!  Don't use them when defining the database.  They just make queries harder to write and to read.
- The `id` column should not be duplicated in `Subscriptions`, so no aggregation is needed.
- On the other hand, `ORDER BY` is usually used with `LIMIT`.
- Use table aliases to simplify the table names.  Just repeating them is not particularly heplful.